# Oracle Tablespace Size Increment

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tablespace

How to increase the size of table space post its max limit. if the max limit is defined as 100M and still later I need to increase it. I have written a query consisting of max size of 100M and now i want to increase it..Please let me know method for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter tablespace datafile 'xxx' size 200m;
```

Also, you can switch "autoextend on" for datafile.